# Tests run fine like Unit Test but fail to run in Test Explorer (Appium & Specflow)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, appium, mstest, specflow

I am working on automation test with Appium and Specflow . Below is my code

```
var objectType = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where type.FullName.Contains("Model.ModelsUI") && 
            type.FullName.Contains(typeObjectName)
            select type).ToList();
```

Everytime I run it in Test Explorer, this statement throw the exception with error message below

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.>

However in the same project, if I make it as [TestMethod] for Unit Testing and run this Unit Test. Then it has no problem and give exact expected result.
I have tried to look for solutions on internet and implement most of them eg: check MsTest Adapter installed, delete obj and bin file then rebuild .... but no cigar though. 
I am new. Please help me with this case. It would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Workaround taken from [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/2008#issuecomment-497612298) raised on Github.

Replace:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

with:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(assembly => !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceDataCollector"))
```